# Grunt not making my chocolatechip.js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs, chocolatechip-ui

I am playing around with (or trying to) use the fast and powerful Chocolatechip UI with there own chocolatechip.js file, but grunt will not make the file for me.

```
"Build is really simple. Just type "grunt" in the terminal and hit return. 
 This will cause a complete version of ChocolateChip-UI to be built into the 
 folder. This will include the ChocolateChipJS library, themes for iOS, Android 
 and Windows, examples for iOS, Android and Windows, and unit tests for 
 ChocolateChipJS."
```

Now when I do this, I get the builds for all mobile platfroms for there CSS and the chui.js. Now I can use this with JQuery, but the chocolatechip.js file looks smaller and works better for app building (if I am wrong with this, please let me know).

But I have no chocolatechip.js file at all??

So what am I doing wrong?

Glenn

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you type grunt?

Comment: I take it that you are talking about the name of the UI, chocolatechip? and yes get your point but this UI seems very good.

Comment: There's not much we can do without more information. Have you tried running Grunt with `--verbose` to see if it's failing somewhere?

Comment: @pstenstrm No errors at all - I think that this is not an issue - I think that I was on an old version of the build process and it looks like they are only using JQuery now

Comment: @andy - I can do? but is there any point? there are no errors been made? + I did not think of that, not using Grunt much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I was right! They now only use JQuery with there UI. - Which I think is a bit pointless, I know the JQuery UI is slow for mobile apps but JQuery 2 is also bigger than most of my needs. So I was looking for something that I could learn that would replace both!

But any ways, there UI plugin now only works with JQuery 2.

I have gone alway form using this. Looking at building my app (well re-building, has it does work, its just slow) using Zepto JS.

Thanks

Glenn.